# Parsing url with webapp2 handler Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Consider the following code:

```
class Activate(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, key):
    self.response.out.write(key)
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/activationlink/([^/]+)?', Activate)],debug=True,config=config)
```

I was wondering how the handler "knows" that the part after /activationlink/ is actually the key? Is it that every URL of a pattern /string/string2 sends a key = string2 to the handler? If so, is it set in the webapp2.RequestHandler class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
class ProductHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self, product_id):
    self.response.write('You requested product %r.' % product_id)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/products/(\d+)', ProductHandler),
])
```

The handler method receives a `product_id` extracted from the URI, and sets a simple message containing the id as response.

As you can see, the `\d+` defines that we are sending a positive integer number.

The parameters are positional. So, if you do this:

```
...
(r'/products/(\d+)/(\d+)', ProductHandler)
...
```

your method would have to receive these parameters (in the order of the url), like this:

```
...
def get(self, param1, param2):
    ...
```

If you want to know more, read the docs here:

- [Request Handlers](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html)
- [URI Routing](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Simple routes section in the webapp2 [URI routing](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html):

> ```
> class ProductHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>     def get(self, product_id):
>         self.response.write('This is the ProductHandler. '
>             'The product id is %s' % product_id)
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>     (r'/', HomeHandler),
>     (r'/products', ProductListHandler),
>     (r'/products/(\d+)', ProductHandler),
> ])
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The regex part is an ordinary regular expression (see the re module)
>   that can define groups inside parentheses. The matched group values
>   are passed to the handler as positional arguments. In the example
>   above, the last route defines a group, so the handler will receive the
>   matched value when the route matches (one or more digits in this
>   case).

In your case `([^/]+)` is the regex group in question, which translates the matching content into the `key` passed to `Activate.get()`.